# Where does asdf install postgres

Tags: postgresql, asdf-vm

I'd like to see to confirm that I don't have multiple versions in the same place, so wanted to know on a Mac where does asdf store postgres. Where does it look when I hit `pg_ctl start`?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `asdf where postgres` which will display the install path for the current version?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know mac, but for linux, it's in your home holder, when you installed 3 versions of postgres, it looks like:

```
~/.asdf/installs/postgres/11.12
~/.asdf/installs/postgres/10.14
~/.asdf/installs/postgres/9.5.25
```

pg_ctl exists in `bin/pg_ctl`

if you want to start a postgres instance, you should :

1. switch to a folder where the `.tool-versions` containing `postgres 9.5.25`
2. `pg_ctl --version` # => 9.5.25
3. `pg_ctl start` # => will start 9.5.25 version of postgres

Answer (score 0):

It puts it into the specified versioned install directory in $HOME/.asdf. They are not in the same place.